# упростить индекс в postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql

Можно ли упростить индекс в postgresql чтоб ощущался прирост скорости, но сам индекс занимал меньше места? Какой лучше использовать

К примеру есть поле с tsrange - тоесть 2 даты со временем.

Данные записываются примерно последовательно.

Нужно чтоб при выборке курсор падал в начало дня (упростить точность времени) и выбирал последовательность большим куском. Дальше в этом куске фильтруем.

Индекс по таблице занимает 50% от размера данных. Интересно как записать больше потратив меньше.

Answer (score 2):

Для такого функциона подходит индекс BRIN:

```
create index collector_time_index
    on radius.collector USING brin (time_range) ;
```